# Why can't a string returned by javascript method be used directly in HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I have a simple javascript helper method like:

```
$scope.getName = function (element) {

  if(element.name.length > 0)
      return element.name;
  else
      return "I've been through a site on an element with no name"
}
```

and I want to write this into an html element such as:

```
<a href="http://bad/song/references"> <font size=10> getName(song)</font></a>
```

I can't do this as I would expect.  Instead I've googled around and all the answers are to create the element and then modify the text of the element programatically later.  I'm wondering why a more convoluted approach such as this is required?  I know PHP methods can be included with a syntax like the above, which is convenient and easier to read, so I'm curious why such a syntax doesn't seem to be recommended/available for javascript.

Again, I'm not necessarily asking how to do what I want, but instead why my naive assumption for syntax isn't/can't be supported.  Of course if there is a simple approach to allowing something like the above I'm just an idiot for not knowing your welcome to call me out for my stupidity, but this is less a question of *how* as *why* from a design/implementation perspective.  I'm more wondering why such a simple syntax doesn't exist, is there some quirk of how javascript and HTML are compiled and processed that prevents the obvious approach of running the method then replacing the method reference with the results?

Comment: `getName(song)` will be interpreted as just text , not as js

Comment: Doing something like `<script>document.write(getName(song))</script>` is doable, but not really maintainable if your site grows more complex. Have you heard about template engines? PHP basically was designed to be a template engine, JavaScript wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP and Javascript operate at two different levels.

PHP runs on the web server that is returning the page.  It can output whatever it wants, and that gets sent to and interpreted by the browser.  Fundamentally, a PHP page compiles to a whole bunch of `echo` statements, whose output is sent along to the browser.  It's up to the browser to interpret that plain text as HTML and build a document structure in memory.

Javascript is running in an environment where the web page has already been interpreted and exists as a structure in memory that the Javascript can manipulate.  While there are ways to send new text back through the interpretation process (e.g. `document.write`), that winds up throwing away a lot of work that the browser has already done and making it do it all over again.

In any case, HTML and Javascript are also two separate languages; outside of `<script>` elements, you can't drop Javascript in the middle of HTML and expect it to work. (Of course, you can't really do that with PHP, either; you need `<?php` or `<?=` tags).

There are Javascript template systems that work like PHP, either on the server side or on the client side (Angular.JS, for instance). But such templates are interpreted by Javascript code in a separate pass from the normal browser rendering process.  Without that special framework code, you just wind up with gobbledygook in your HTML.

Comment: OH...yeah PHP is server side.  I haven't touched PHP in ages (I decided I hated it so much that I refused to do *any* web development for a long time).  Somehow in the years of avoiding webpages I completely blanked out that it was a server side language, but remembering that the difference in syntax makes complete sense, and I feel stupid.  I does make me wonder if a theoretical new HTML-like language could be written in a way to allow client side languages to have this convenience, by messing with order of processing, or if this is an inevitable limitation of two languages playing together

Comment: ...and you answered my question even as I was writing it, stop doing that ;)  good answer and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's content.  How would HTML interpreter know whether to execute it or display it?  Content has to be set, not run in place.  As a minimum you have to wrap content in script tags to tell it to execute/evaluate it.

Answer (score 0):

simplest reason, what if you want to display text "getName(song)"? how browser/html parser will distinguish between "function invocation" and "plain text"

actually, reason a little bit deeper:

HTML is not programming language, it is markup language, which is the only purpose is to format text. HTML was created around 1991.

> The Hypertext Markup Language (HTML) is a simple markup language used to create hypertext documents that are platform independent.

Javascript was created to manipulate DOM 4 years after HTML was introduced.

> ECMAScript is an object-oriented programming language for performing computations and manipulating computational objects within a host environment.

And its addition was backward compatible. Which means: HTML doesnt know about javascript, javascript knows about HTML. Special tag was created to separate HTML and Javascript from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Look into a templating engine such as [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) to accomplish what you're looking for.

It is not possible natively because the browser interprets HTML and Javascript differently and there is a separation of markup and logic (this is a good thing).